# Invalid_grant Error while Running Experiment in Smart Target

Tags: smarttarget

I Created one Experiment by Following SDL Documentation. I can see all Component Presentations on my DD4T Web Application Page but when i click on my Experiment in CME to see the statistics it throws the Error says :

```
   com.tridion.smarttarget.SmartTargetException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
  {
    "error" : "invalid_grant"
 }
at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:210) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
at com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.AnalyticsManager.getStatistics(AnalyticsManager.java:184) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
at com.tridion.smarttarget.experiments.Experiment.loadStatistics(Experiment.java:198) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
at com.tridion.smarttarget.webservices.experiments.ExperimentResolver.getExperimentsWithStatistics(ExperimentResolver.java:148) ~[smarttarget_api_webservice.jar:na]
at com.tridion.smarttarget.webservices.experiments.ExperimentResolver.resolveCollection(ExperimentResolver.java:57) ~[smarttarget_api_webservice.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.resolve(ResolverBase.java:74) [cd_odata.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataFeedRenderer.renderODataFeed(ODataFeedRenderer.java:45) [cd_odata.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleODataEntity(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:141) [cd_odata.jar:na]
at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleResourceRequest(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:117) [cd_odata.jar:na]
```

It seems Google Analytics API is not Authorizing the token (P12 key in our case), do i need to do anything different for OATH Authentication.

Note : I have Set Up Analytics mentioned in SDL Docs,and i can see Statistics for my DD4T Application Pages on https://analytics.google.com/analytics/

This is what i used in my Smart Target Config File :

```
  <Analytics implementationClass="com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager" timeoutMilliseconds="5000" trackingRedirectUrl="/redirect/">
        <ServiceAccountEmailAddress>neelesh.raghuvanshi@tieto.com</ServiceAccountEmailAddress>
        <PrivatekeyPath>C:\NeelNew\Tieto Project-d6daec6b60f9.p12</PrivatekeyPath>
        <AccountId>74328616</AccountId>
        <TrackingId>UA-74328616-1</TrackingId>
        <ViewId>117415479</ViewId>
        <CustomDimensions>
            <ExperimentId>1</ExperimentId>
            <PublicationTargetId>2</PublicationTargetId>
            <PublicationId>3</PublicationId>
            <PageId>4</PageId>
            <Region>5</Region>
            <ComponentId>6</ComponentId>
            <ComponentTemplateId>7</ComponentTemplateId>
            <ChosenVariant>8</ChosenVariant>
        </CustomDimensions>
    </Analytics>
```

I wonder if Service Account Email Address is my Google Account through which i logged in to Google, is it true? Also please suggest me what i am missing. Do i neeed to do anything extra apart from the Documentation on SDL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Service Account Email, doesn't need to be the one you use to log on google analytics pages.

The Service Account Email is the one you use to generate de `.p12` file.

Then in Google Analytics Admin of the site you want to use, this `Account Service Email`, must be granted in the "`User Management`" tab. With at least "`Read and Analyze`" permission.

Like in the image:

[image]

Comment: Although i am getting new error now which says com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value 'ga:1==6ac8d87e-0498-4b5d-bf47-4591016a866b;ga:2==tcm:0-4-65537' for filters parameter.",
    "reason" : "invalidParameter"
  } ], Do i need to add any tracking code for components tracing, i am confused how it tracks components added in experiment

Comment: Where ga:1 is PromotionId andga:2 is PublicationtargetId which i can see while debugging the experiments.

Comment: I recommend you to post another question with the error in detail, as it seems different from the original cause.

Comment: I have Created a new question. http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/error-invalid-value-for-filter-parameteres-in-smart-target-experiments. Thanks