# Error "Invalid value for Filter Parameteres" in Smart Target Experiments

Tags: smarttarget

This is related to my old question on Experiment :
[Invalid_grant Error while Running Experiment in Smart Target](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14039/invalid-grant-error-while-running-experiment-in-smart-target)

I Created one Experiment by Following SDL Documentation. I can see all Component Presentations on my DD4T Web Application Page but when i click on my Experiment in CME to see the statistics it throws the Error says :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
 "code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Invalid value 'ga:1==6ac8d87e-0498-4b5d-bf47-4591016a866b;ga:2==tcm:0-4-65537' for filters parameter.",
"reason" : "invalidParameter"
} ],
"message" : "Invalid value 'ga:1==6ac8d87e-0498-4b5d-bf47-4591016a866b;ga:2==tcm:0-4-65537' for filters parameter."
}
```

Note : While Debugging i can see I am getting Two Promotions in FredhopperResultSet, One For Experiments and One for Promotion and while Expanding Experiments i can see 6ac8d87e-0498-4b5d-bf47-4591016a866b is my PromotionId and tcm:0-4-65537 is my PublicationTargetId.

Just FYI that i am Working on my Localhost and made a Host Entry for www.xyz.com and Created a Google Analytics Account for www.xyz.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking the configuration you posted in the previous question : [Invalid_grant Error while Running Experiment in Smart Target](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14039/invalid-grant-error-while-running-experiment-in-smart-target) maybe the problem is the dimension configuration, try setting as:

```
        <CustomDimensions>
            <ExperimentId>dimension1</ExperimentId>
            <PublicationTargetId>dimension2</PublicationTargetId>
            <PublicationId>dimension3</PublicationId>
            <PageId>dimension4</PageId>
            <Region>dimension5</Region>
            <ComponentId>dimension6</ComponentId>
            <ComponentTemplateId>dimension7</ComponentTemplateId>
            <ChosenVariant>dimension8</ChosenVariant>
        </CustomDimensions>
```

with the word **dimension** included.